# Parsing and Modifying $PATH using Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am attempting to parse through the path variable and remove any directory structure to JAVA_HOME or an alternate location where JAVA is installed on windows.  The end goal is to remove the locations from the path variable and reset the variable.  This is what I have started.

```
    SETLOCAL
SET TEMPPATH="%PATH%"

SET NEWPATH =""

CALL :parse %TEMPPATH%

GOTO :NEXT

:PARSE

SET list=%1

SET list=%list:"=%

FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a IN ("%list%") DO (

   ::ECHO A: %%a
   ::ECHO B: %%b

   IF NOT "%%a"=="%VAR_JAVA_HOME%" CALL :SUB "%%a"

   IF NOT "%%b"=="" CALL :PARSE "%%b"   

)
exit /b

:SUB

::echo in subroutine

::echo Passed into subroutine: %1

::echo NEW PATH is: "%NEWPATH%"

IF DEFINED NEWPATH IF %NEWPATH%==""(

   SET NEWPATH=%1;

   ECHO "IN SUB:" %NEWPATH%

   )

IF DEFINED NEWPATH IF "NEWPATH:~1, %1"==""(

   SET NEWPATH="%NEWPATH%";%1

   ECHO %NEWPATH%

)
ECHO "New path varible:" "%NEWPATH%"

exit /b

:NEXT
::ECHO "Removed Java entries from the path..."

ENDLOCAL
```

When the script runs I get this error:
"C:\Windows was unexpected at this time."

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Russ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious issues are:

- there are no spaces before block-opening `(` in each `IF`.
- `::` comments inside the loop; switch to `rem .....`.
- `NEWPATH:~1, %1` is syntactically incorrect; use `%NEWPATH:~1%` to extract starting from the second character or `%NEWPATH:~0,1%` to extract only the first character, for example. More help is available by running `set /?` in the command prompt console.

P.S. Also consider using indents for labelled subroutines:

```c
:PARSE
    SET list=%1
    SET list=%list:"=%
    ..................
:SUB
    ::echo in subroutine
    ..................
:NEXT
    ..................
```